# Firefox: how to put bookmarks back on bookmarks toolbar?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, toolbar

I removed "Bookmarks Toolbar Items" (can be found in "View -> Toolbars -> Customize") from bookmarks toolbar. So it's empty now - no buttons, separators or any other toolbar objects.  Before I removed the only item from the toolbar it was below adress toolbar and above tabs toolbar. Now it disappeared (it's checked though in "View->Toolbars").

I don't know how put the "Bookmarks Toolbar Items" back to the toolbar because it's empty and therefore hidden. I tried dragging the Bookmarks Toolbar Items into different spots between address bar and tabs toolbar, but it didn't work.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried resetting defaults in that same customize dialog (view -> toolbars -> customize)?

That should bring it back, although you'll need to tweak your toolbars again to the way you like.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
Now I'm wondering why didn't I try it before asking the question. Probably I tried but it didn't work for some reason (too much customization maybe).

Anyway, I have my bookmarks icons back :)